# JQuery behavior of text() vs .parent().html() for subsequent changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had a scenario in my code where I was previously updating a div using element.text(data) every time a button was clicked.

I've since updated this, because I need to pass html into the div now instead of text. As such, the call is now element.parent().html(data).

It works correctly the first time the button is clicked, but seems to have the unintended side-effect of only ever allowing me to update it once, now. I changed it back to .text() just to be certain, and sure enough I was able to click my button multiple times with different content, and get that content in there. Unique content just won't make any updates via that parent().html(). Can someone explain what's going on here?

Here's the code that works every time:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#count").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                //[... gets some parameters in here ...]

                $.post("myfile.php", {argument = list, goes = here}, function(data){
                    $("#subcount").text("Submission Count: " + data);
                });

            })
        })
```

And here's the code that only fires once:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#count").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                //[... gets some parameters in here ...]

                $.post("myfile.php", {argument = list, goes = here}, function(data){
                    $("#subcount").parent().html(data);
                });

            })
        })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: When you are using `element.parent().html(data)` it overwrites the content of parent hence `element` is no longer part of DOM hence it does't works second time. It would be better if you post the relevant code so that we can help you.

Comment: That makes sense. Just posted the code.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and content of `data`? for better understanding

Comment: The data was just an int or a string in the first case, and in the second case it is a small table with two rows <table><tr><td>key1</td><td>val1</td></tr><tr><td>key2</td><td>val2</td></tr></table>    very simply. Or did you mean the HTML of #subcount, where the data is being injected?

Comment: Unless `data` includes an element with id `subcount`, after changing the parent HTML, the target will no longer exist.  Try wrapping your `data` string in `<div id = "subcount">....</div>`

Comment: @sideroxylon, that is the correct answer. If you post it as such, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `data` includes an element with id `subcount`, after changing the parent HTML, the target will no longer exist.

Try wrapping your data string in:

```
<div id = "subcount">....</div>
```

Then you will have a target for the next button click.